# Defining custom merge function to resolve InMemoryCache merge in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm getting a warning:

```
Cache data may be lost when replacing the parts field of a Query object.

To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), define a custom merge function for the Query.parts field, so InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects:

  existing: [{"__ref":"Part:53"},{"__ref":"Part:55"},{"__ref":"Part:56"},{"__ref":"Part:57"},{"__ref":"Part:58"}]
  incoming: [{"__ref":"Part:53"},{"__ref":"Part:55"},{"__ref":"Part:56"},{"__ref":"Part:57"}]
```

Now here is my Part type:

```
type Part {
  id: ID!
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
  partName: String
  partDescription: String
  partQuantity: Long
  usePercentage: Boolean
  partPercentage: Float
  type: String
  published_at: DateTime
  products(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Product]
  partImage(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UploadFile]
  stockevents(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Stockevent]
}
```

This warning triggers after I remove one part using mutation to delete a single part. Here it is:

```
const [partDelete] = useMutation(DELETE_PART, {
        update(cache, { data }) {
            const newData = Object.values(data)
            const refresh = newData.map(name => name.part)
            const refined = refresh.map(item => item.id)
            cache.evict({
                id: cache.identify({
                    id: refined.id
                })
            })
            cache.writeQuery({
                query: GET_PARTS
            })
        },
        refetchQueries: [
          { query: GET_PARTS }
        ]
    })
```

I am passing payload in a separate function and everything works but I keep getting this cache warning so I want to deal with it now.

I've went with updating InMemoryCache in my index.js but it still doesn't work:

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Part: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = []) {
            return [...existing, ...incoming];
          }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

I've also tried to return only ...incoming but nothing different happens.

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: `for the Query.part**s** field` ... `writeQuery` without `data`??? read docs

Comment: @xadm thanks for the info but the suggestion is completely irrelevant to my problem. I have solved it on my own.

Comment: show solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the structure of InMemoryCache config. After I changed it to this it worked:

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        Part: {
          parts: {
            fields: {
              merge(existing, incoming) {
                return incoming;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

I have also removed update option from the mutation that includes evict and modify.

Comment: it was about partsssssssssss ... and update/writeQuery was wrong, you can still fix it to make visual updates faster

Comment: @xadm yea, before trying to write them as you said according to docs I've tried without them and it worked hah

Answer (score -1):

when you see this warning:

> To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), define a custom merge function for the Query.your_query_name field, so InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects:

try this for shorten:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "your_API_link",
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          your_Query_Name: {
            merge: (existing = [], incoming) => {
              return incoming;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }),
});
```